# What are the consequences of leaving a domain name's TTL value low

Tags: domains, web-hosting

My host recommends lowering the TTL value of my domain prior to making DNS changes and then suggests that I should raise them after changes are finsihed.  What are the negative consequences of leaving the values low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTL ("Time To Live") setting tells DNS clients how long they may cache the results of their DNS queries - if you set the value too low (for example, to "1" for one second) the load on your DNS server will increase dramatically once the original TTL has expired (i.e. if your TTL is set to "3600" but you change it to "1", you will probably see an increase in DNS queries after an hour).